# Batch inserts into google cloud sql 2nd generation

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Can we make batch inserts into google cloud sql 2nd generation instance from 
Standard App engine instance ??

If so what is the limit ?

Please down vote the question, I have checked the docs but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, you can create the batch request in the same way you would creating the batch request in a standard MySQL instance from a standard application (here an example in [java](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/)).
The limit reported in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/how-tos/batch) are 1000 calls for a single batch request